# Extracting single key from object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I'm looking at extracting keys from an Object and push them to an array in Javascript (Nodejs). An example would be:

```
var obj = [{tag: 'ft001', addr: 'DB415.DBD2'}, {tag: 'ft001', addr: 'DB415.DBD6'}];

function extractKey(arr, keyName) { 

// Result: ['ft001', 'ft002'];

}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: have you tried `forEach` or `map` functions?

Comment: `var keys = obj.map(function(x) {return x.tag});`

Comment: Something like `obj.map(o=>o.tag)` should go close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var obj = [{tag: 'ft001', addr: 'DB415.DBD2'}, {tag: 'ft001', addr: 'DB415.DBD6'}];

function extractKey(arr, keyName) { 
  return arr.map(x=> x[keyName])
}
```

I think it's rather self-explaining.

Answer (score 1):

if a typo [ 'ft001', 'ft002'], then the following would you be useful:

```
function extractKey() {
    var result = [];
    for (var index = 0; index < obj.length; index++) {
        result.push(obj[index].tag);        
    }
    return result;
// Result: ['ft001', 'ft001'];
}
```